# how to update apps for new iPhone resolution

Tags: iphone, ios

The new iPhone is being presented..
it has a new resolution aspect ratio. (1136 x 640)

Does anyone know how to upgrade apps to support the new resolution??

Thanks!

Comment: We don't have this information yet. Check developer.apple.com.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393899/ensure-ios-app-is-not-letterboxed-on-the-iphone-5

Comment: just asking.. isn't normal?? isn't the purpose of stackoverflow!?

Comment: If nothing else, one can start by getting rid of any hard coded `frame`/`bounds` in your code, and start to use the `size` of the superview. I can't tell you how often I've seen code here explicitly referencing screen dimensions of 320 x 480 or putting buttons on the screen using hard coded coordinates.

Comment: yes, that's true.. it's not the case, don't usually do it

Comment: Rob, I think your answer is not correct. At the presentation they said that old apps will be shown with frame. May be we need to add new strings to the Info.plist...

Comment: Why don't we hold off on the conjecture and just check out the next SDK Apple releases?

Answer (score 0):

Normal UI components like buttons etc. should be update with the new SDK - Like on the MBP Retnia. But graphics you have made like images, needs to be update with a bigger dpi - This is only a guess, but that was how it work to MBP Retnia

Comment: yes, but if the resolution isn't the same, maybe buttons, etc.. will be placed differently

Answer (score 0):

We are using [Canappi](http://www.ebpml.org/blog2/index.php/2012/09/13/easy-iphone-5-screen-resolution) to generate the Objective-C code that works on both resolutions (and with iPad too). Canappi works like Interface Builder, but in a textual form (which is much easier to use if you ask me). This is how you specify the position of your controls for each resolution and/or form factor:

```
layout myTabletLayout {

     text name (10,60,100,30) { ... }

}

layout myPhoneLayout {

    text name (10,60,100,30 + 0,10,0,2) { ... }

    tablet myTabletLayout ;

}
```

the +0,10,0,2 is a shift that is applied to the original coordinates when the app runs on an iPhone 5. That means that you can easily resize tables, space out controls or even, and that's really cool, bring controls which are displayed off screen on the iPhone 4, back into the iPhone 5 view bounds.